# jQuery mobile - persisting the last page the user was on?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm trying to bring the user back to the page they closed the application on (`<div id="#blah" data-role="page">`), but I can't seem to find a way to do this elegantly within the library.

How do I do this?

I tried storing the page id to localStorage and calling `$.mobile.changePage` at the end of `$(document).ready`, but that throws odd exceptions. Only using a timeout with `changePage` seems to work, but it's inelegant as the first page is shown first.

Comment: are the pages in a multi-page layout or are they dynamically created? Can you manually navigate to the page you want?

Comment: It's a multi-page layout, and I can manually navigate.
Try using http://www.wendler.mobi in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are having a timing issue here. Why not just change the page once it has been created? You haven't provided all the details about how your pages are being rendered. Like whether they are coming from an HTML document, or being dynamically created using JavaScript before JQM has JQMModfied the page or dynamically after JQM has JQMModified the page.

```
$('#IdFromStorage').live('createpage', function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('#IdFromStorage');
});
```

You can find more information about the createpage event here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Comment: It's all flat HTML, but you have to be right that it's a timing issue. I didn't know if there was anything better I could do to combat this, but the `createpage` event looks like exactly what I need. I'll accept once I've tested the solution.